# How to parse slightly ambiguous data using nom?

Tags: rust, nom

In [RFC1738](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc1738.txt), the BNF for `domainlabel` is the following:

> domainlabel    = alphadigit | alphadigit *[ alphadigit | "-" ]
>   alphadigit

That is, it's either an alphadigit, or it's a string where the first/last characters have to be an alphadigit but the intermediate characters can be an alphadigit or a dash.

How do I implement this with [nom](https://docs.rs/nom)? Ignoring the single character scenario to simplify the case, my final attempt is:

```rust
fn domain_label(s: &[u8]) -> IResult<&[u8], (&[u8], &[u8], &[u8])> {
    let left = take_while_m_n(1, 1, is_alphanumeric);
    let middle = take_while(|c| is_alphanumeric(c) || c == b'-');
    let right = take_while_m_n(1, 1, is_alphanumeric);
    let whole = tuple((left, middle, right));
    whole(s)
}
```

The problem with this is that `middle` can consume the last character and hence `right` fails because there is no character to consume.

```rust
println!("{:?}", domain_label(b"abcde"));
Err(Error(([], TakeWhileMN)))
```

Parsers should be able to attempt all possible consumption paths, but how to do this with `nom`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> domainlabel = alphadigit | alphadigit *[ alphadigit | "-" ] alphadigit

It is a series of alphanumeric sequence delimited by any number of character `-`. So here is one way to do it:

```rust
use nom::bytes::complete::{tag, take_while1};
use nom::character::is_alphanumeric;
use nom::combinator::recognize;
use nom::multi::{many1, separated_list};
use nom::IResult;

fn domain_label(input: &[u8]) -> IResult<&[u8], &[u8]> {
    let alphadigits = take_while1(is_alphanumeric);
    let delimiter = many1(tag(b"-"));
    let parser = separated_list(delimiter, alphadigits);

    recognize(parser)(input)
}

fn main() {
    let (_, res) = domain_label(b"abcde").unwrap();
    assert_eq!(res, b"abcde");
    let (_, res) = domain_label(b"abcde-123-xyz-").unwrap();
    assert_eq!(res, b"abcde-123-xyz");
    let (_, res) = domain_label(b"rust-lang--1---37---0.org").unwrap();
    assert_eq!(res, b"rust-lang--1---37---0");
}
```

Notice, you don't need individual parts of a successful parsing. The result is just the longest input that conforms to the domain label BNF. That's where the `recognize` combinator comes in.

Comment: Thanks. That solves the immediate problem, but it sidestepped the issue I noted which is that ambiguous parsing could require backtracking. Does nom do this or must one rely on converting the grammar into a parsing solution that doesn't require backtracking?

Comment: @Listerone, in this specific case, there's no ambiguity. And you may notice my 3rd test case, which doesn't consume all the input. You can continue parse whatever left with any parser you wish. That's also the strategy to deal with failure / ambiguity; you try other options with remaining input. Until there's no option left or all input consumed w/o success, then that's a hard failure.

Comment: @Listerone there's also [`peek`](https://docs.rs/nom/5.0.1/nom/combinator/fn.peek.html) combinator that is specifically designed to **not** consume the input.